# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Entity Framework Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

In the past I have seen clear printouts of the SQL statements from Entity Framework sent to the logger, historically by setting `DbContext.Database.Log`. Things seem to have changed and I can't get them to work.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v2) by MS implies that configuring logging for ASP.NET Core automatically configures entity logging.  Following this I have configured the logging using the `appsettings.json` file as below:

```
{
   "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Debug",
    }
  }
}
```

This does result in lots of logs from the Entity Framework Core showing up, however none of them are the queries.  I would expect to see entries from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command` but I do not. How do I get the SQL statements in the logs?

I know this looks similar to a few other questions, but none of them helped me out.

Update: All the responses were on the right track.  The actual issue was the provider in use.  For preliminary development we were using the in memory database.  This provider does not log SQL statements (it isn't an SQL database).  For completeness the logger configuration needed to be:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue? I tried to reproduce your issue and even with the most minimal example I can up with it works and logs `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name]
FROM [Users] AS [c]`. I'll upload the code to github and add the link.

Comment: [Simple EF6-style Logging for EF Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2017/09/22/simple-logging-for-ef-core/)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Compufreak345/Example_AspNetCore2_2_EfCore_QueryLogging) is a working example with .Net Core 2.2 and mostly everything being default. There must be something off with your code we can't see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the one I stole out of Adam Freeman's Pro Entity Framework Core 2 book
and I see the sql statements

https://github.com/Apress/pro-ef-core-2-for-asp.net-core-mvc/blob/master/03%20-%20Working%20with%20Databases/PartyInvites/PartyInvites/appsettings.json

```
{
"Logging":{
     "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "None",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: You can refine it a little further if desired: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"

Comment: Hello, in my case, I dont want these INFO logs from EF to show up or log to my logging source (text file). Currently i set them all as "warning" but still these INFO logs from EF are showing up. How do i avoid them?

Comment: `"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking": "Warning"
    },`